# Child DIV change height to match other child DIV

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have scoured the internet looking for a solution to this and I am sure it is right under my nose. Will someone please help?

I have a parent div with two children. Each child has static widths and I need each one to change their height to match the other according to the content. In other words, If "child-div-a" is taller than "child-div-b, then "child-div-b" needs to automatically scale the same height of "child-div-a". I have been able to get the parent to scale to the largest child but not the other child. I cannot seem to get the left div (a) to always be the same height as the right/content div (b). You would think this would be very simple or maybe I'm an idiot.

Thank you in advance for all help.

Joshua

---

**My probelm has been solved.**

The first response I saw from japanPro contained a link to Ed Elliot's blog. That contained info on faux columns. I fairly simple concept that I can't believe I didn't see. It was all smoke and mirrors, but I was too focussed on the illusion to see how the trick can be done (if that makes any since). Here is the CSS I came up with:

```
#child-div-container{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(../../../images/faux_column_bkground.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }

 #child-div-a{
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    }

 #child-div-b{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

Thank you again to everyone who responded to my needs. Everyone gave viable information. I only hope I can develop my skils and knowledge to the point of offering advice instead of asking for it.

Joshua

Comment: *You would think this would be very simple or maybe I'm an idiot.* - no, you're not an idiot: equal-heights is just one of the many, many omissions from CSS... =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is two way to do

- javascript way , use jquery equal height

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

- other way is using css

http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Comment: Where did the third column come from? And why is there style for an unused container2?

Comment: i was trying with my exiting demo , which is working and not broken; any way ; you can get same here http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Comment: The faux column trick, suggested by Ed Eliot on his blog, works great for my application. I knew it was something simple, I just needed to think out side of the box (no pun intended). I prefer to stay away from javascript as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a good CSS-based answer for you. But you can accomplish this easily with jQuery.

Suppose you have the following markup

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>My content</div>
  <div>Other div with content</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/) that lets you do this as simply as:

```
$("#parent div").equalHeights();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I prefer to stay away from jquery and javascript as much as I can for layout issues. I used a faux column trick suggested by Ed Elliot on his blog. That was suggested to me by japanPro. Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem in html/css. There's tricks to do this in Javascript, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Two solutions for this problem that don't use javascript:

[Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) - Only works if the background of the column that has to stretch  has only one background color or a repeating pattern (because it uses an image or border to fake a column). This might not work as well though when you can't predict with div will be taller.

[Equal Height Columns](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) - CSS trick that I haven't yet tested.

Comment: Thank you too for your suggestion. By the time I got this far down on the page, I already fixed my problem. I went with the faux column trick. Very lightweight and does not rely on javascript. I did forget to mention in my original post that I was hoping for native CSS. Thank you again for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery method as I found on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/equalize-heights-of-divs/) an EXCELLENT resource!

> var maxHeight = 0;
>
> ```
> $("div").each(function(){
>    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight =
> ```
>
> $(this).height(); }
>       });
>
> ```
> $("div").height(maxHeight);
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I used a faux column trick to do the job. I wanted native CSS anyways. Thanks again.